# Why do I get different code objects from compile(my_func) and my_func.__code__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Firstly, I asked the question on CodeReview: [Exploring code objects](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/216944/153727). But then, I tried another approach and got different code object field values by the `compile()` and `my_func.__code__`. Shouldn't they be the same? If not, where I can read about differences between `compile` and `__code__`?

```
# Function for exploring
def my_add(a,b):
    first = a
    second = b

    return first + second

# Print all code object fields
def print_co_obj_fields(code_obj):
    # Iterating through all instance attributes
    # and calling all having the 'co_' prefix
    for name in dir(code_obj):
        if name.startswith('co_'):
            co_field = getattr(code_obj, name)
            print(f'{name:<20} = {co_field}')

### Making the code object for 'my_add' function
# First approach
code_obj_compile = compile('my_add', os.path.realpath(__file__), 'exec')

# Second approach
code_obj_dunder = my_add.__code__

print("=" * 60)
print("code_obj_compile output")
print("=" * 60)
print_co_obj_fields(code_obj_compile)

print("=" * 60)
print("code_obj_dunder output")
print("=" * 60)

print_co_obj_fields(code_obj_dunder)
```

**Output - partially different (`co_code`, `co_argcount`, etc...):**

```
============================================================
code_obj_compile output
============================================================
co_argcount          = 0 
co_cellvars          = ()
co_code              = b'e\x00\x01\x00d\x00S\x00'
co_consts            = (None,)
co_filename          = /home/minimax/learning_python/oop/source.py
co_firstlineno       = 1 
co_flags             = 64
co_freevars          = ()
co_kwonlyargcount    = 0 
co_lnotab            = b'' 
co_name              = <module>
co_names             = ('my_add',)
co_nlocals           = 0 
co_stacksize         = 1 
co_varnames          = ()
============================================================
code_obj_dunder output
============================================================
co_argcount          = 2
co_cellvars          = ()
co_code              = b'|\x00}\x02|\x01}\x03|\x02|\x03\x17\x00S\x00'
co_consts            = (None,)
co_filename          = ./source.py
co_firstlineno       = 21
co_flags             = 67
co_freevars          = ()
co_kwonlyargcount    = 0 
co_lnotab            = b'\x00\x01\x04\x01\x04\x02'
co_name              = my_add
co_names             = ()
co_nlocals           = 4 
co_stacksize         = 2 
co_varnames          = ('a', 'b', 'first', 'second')
```

Comment: Because `my_add` is not the same as the code in your `my_add` function. In the first, you merely reference a name, `my_add`, use `dis.dis` to see a good representation of the bytecode and it should become obvious

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know the difference between reference to the object and the object itself. But then, how can I compile `my_add` using `compile()` function to match `my_add.__code__`? If I will do `compile('my_add()', ....)` it also will be different, because of calling function.

Comment: Do you have an actual use for this, or are doing it only out of curiosity?

Comment: @martineau Out of curiosity. I am learning how Python interpreter works under the hood and this question was raised, when I have known about code objects and tried to look at them. The first question was on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/216944/153727)